# MuJoCo. What is the difference between pos, qpos, and xpos?

Tags: mujoco

Can someone give a simple explanation of the difference between these in MuJoCo?

These often come together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mjModel.foo_pos` is the position of a thing in its parent, like the position of a geom in a body. These quantities are fixed and defined the shape of the model (hence, they are in `mjModel`).

`mjData.qpos` are the joint angles. This is the configuration and constitutes half of the *mechanical state* (the other half being `mjData.qvel`). Generally any name that starts with `q` means "in joint space".

`mjData.foo_xpos` means Cartesian positions in the global world frame. Again, any name that starts with `x` means "in global Cartesian space".